# Redux Persist state is not storing when fetching api using axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I am fetching an api with axios and the action is being fired after the "persist/REHYDRATE" action resulting in the following
"redux-persist/autoRehydrate: 1 actions were fired before rehydration completed...."

If I delete a tweet one by one and then refresh my browser, it does not store the state. Can't seem to crack this..

Client.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { compose, applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import logger from "redux-logger"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware"
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist'
import tweetApp from "./reducers"
import Layout from "./components/Layout"
import { REHYDRATE } from 'redux-persist/constants'
import createActionBuffer from 'redux-action-buffer'

//const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger())
let enhancer = compose(
  autoRehydrate({ log: true }),
  applyMiddleware(
    promise(), thunk, logger(), createActionBuffer(REHYDRATE)
  )
)
const store = createStore(
  tweetApp,
  enhancer
);
const persistConfig = {
  whitelist : ["tweets"]
};
persistStore(store, persistConfig);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Layout />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

tweetsReducer.js

```
import {REHYDRATE} from 'redux-persist/constants'

export default function reducer(state={
    tweets: [],
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    error: null,
  }, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case "persist/REHYDRATE": {
        const incoming = action.payload.tweets; // Carts is the name of the reducer
        if (incoming) return {...state, ...incoming}
      }
      case "FETCH_TWEETS": {
        return {...state, fetching: true}
      }
      case "FETCH_TWEETS_REJECTED": {
        return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
      }
      case "FETCH_TWEETS_FULFILLED": {
        return {
          ...state,
          fetching: false,
          fetched: true,
          tweets: action.payload,
        }
      }
      case "ADD_TWEET": {
        return {
          ...state,
          tweets: [...state.tweets, action.payload],
        }
      }
      case "UPDATE_TWEET": {
        const { id, text } = action.payload
        const newTweets = [...state.tweets]
        const tweetToUpdate = newTweets.findIndex(tweet => tweet.id === id)
        newTweets[tweetToUpdate] = action.payload;

        return {
          ...state,
          tweets: newTweets,
        }
      }
      case "DELETE_TWEET": {
        return {
          tweets: [
              ...state.tweets.slice(0, action.payload),
              ...state.tweets.slice(action.payload + 1)
          ],
        }
      }
    }

    return state
}
```

tweetsActions.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export function fetchTweets() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get("http://rest.learncode.academy/api/test123/tweets")
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_FULFILLED",  payload: response.data})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type: "FETCH_TWEETS_REJECTED", payload: err})
      })
  }
}

export function addTweet(id, text) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TWEET',
    payload: {
      id,
      text,
    },
  }
}

export function updateTweet(id, text) {
  return {
    type: 'UPDATE_TWEET',
    payload: {
      id,
      text,
    },
  }
}

export function deleteTweet(id) {
  return { type: 'DELETE_TWEET', payload: id}
}
```

layouts.js

```
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { fetchUser } from "../actions/userActions"
import { fetchTweets } from "../actions/tweetsActions"
import { deleteTweet } from "../actions/tweetsActions"

@connect((store) => {
  return {
    user: store.user.user,
    userFetched: store.user.fetched,
    tweets: store.tweets.tweets,
  };
})

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUser())
    this.props.dispatch(fetchTweets())
  }

  fetchTweets() {
    //this.props.dispatch(fetchTweets())
  }

  deleteTweet(idx, e) {
    this.props.dispatch(deleteTweet(idx))
  }

  render() {
    const { user, tweets, i } = this.props;
    //console.log(this.props)
    const mappedTweets = tweets.map((tweet, i) => <li key={i}>{tweet.text}<button onClick={this.deleteTweet.bind(this, i)}>delete</button></li>)

    return <div>
      <h1>{user.name}</h1>
      <ul>{mappedTweets}</ul>
    </div>
  }
}
```

UPDATE AND SAME ISSUE:
I tried replacing "componentWILLMount() with componentDidMount()" and the issue still occurs. See logged output: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Move your `fetchTweets` and `fetchUser` calls to `componentDidMount`, otherwise all your code is executed synchronously: from the store being created to your Layout being instantiated and rendered.

`componentWillMount` is called before render, while `componentDidMount` is called after the component has been rendered for the first time.

Comment: gave that a go and still no luck. See above, I updated the answer.